# selecting answers on community wikis

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answer-format, moderation

Shouldn't when i select a community wiki as the option type. It should remove the select answer notification.

Or alternately select the highest upped question as the answer dynamically?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I think its fine as-is. It's perfectly acceptable for a community wiki question to have one right answer.

Comment: I disagree. community wikis are usually discussions about things and best practices, which can consist of many different types of ideas and answers.